# how to write into a vector which is defined globally and outside the pthread function

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

In this code, when I output using `cout` then it isn't showing any errors, but when I write the value of `x` in `queuedensity()` function, it throws an segmentation fault error. Does anyone know what I should do to push the value of `x` corresponding to an `i` and `step_i` in my `queuedensity()` function?

```cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <pthread.h>
// #include<mutex>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

pthread_mutex_t lock;
// mutex mm;
string video;
int threads;
int core = -1;
vector<Mat> frames;
Mat backgroundImage;

vector<vector<double>> density(718, vector<double>(threads, 0));

vector<Mat> Mdivide(Mat img)
{
    vector<Mat> blocks;
    int sizeX = img.size[0];
    int sizeY = img.size[1];
    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
    {
        Mat temp = img(Rect(0.0, double(778 * i / threads), 328.0, 778 / threads * 1.0));
        blocks.push_back(temp);
    }
    return blocks;
}
        
Mat croppedframe(Mat frames)
{
    Mat ret;

    Mat im_src = frames;
    Mat gray_img;
    cvtColor(im_src, gray_img, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    Size size;
    size = im_src.size();
    Mat im_dst = Mat::zeros(size, CV_8UC3);

    // Create a vector of destination points.
    vector<Point2f> final_pts;

    final_pts.push_back(Point2f(472, 52));
    final_pts.push_back(Point2f(472, 830));
    final_pts.push_back(Point2f(800, 830));
    final_pts.push_back(Point2f(800, 52));

    vector<Point2f> initial_pts;

    initial_pts.push_back(Point2f(966, 210));
    initial_pts.push_back(Point2f(446, 714));
    initial_pts.push_back(Point2f(1448, 714));
    initial_pts.push_back(Point2f(1288, 207));

    Mat h1 = findHomography(initial_pts, final_pts);
    warpPerspective(gray_img, im_dst, h1, size);
    Mat cropedImage = im_dst(Rect(472, 52, 328, 778));
    ret = cropedImage;
    return ret;
}

void print(vector<Mat> a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    {
        imshow("frame", a[i]);

        waitKey(0);
    }
}

void *queuedensity(void *p)
{
    Ptr<BackgroundSubtractor> bg_model;
    bg_model = createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("queue_method3.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < frames.size(); i++)
    {
        Mat img1 = croppedframe(frames[i]);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        core = (core + 1);
        core = core % threads;
        int step_i = core;
        vector<Mat> blocks;
        blocks = Mdivide(img1);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

        Mat img = blocks[step_i];
        Mat foregroundMask;
        foregroundMask.create(backgroundImage.size(), backgroundImage.type());

        // compute foreground mask 8 bit image
        bg_model->apply(img, foregroundMask, 0);
        // smooth the mask to reduce noise in image
        GaussianBlur(foregroundMask, foregroundMask, Size(11, 11), 3.5, 3.5);
        // threshold mask to saturate at black and white values
        threshold(foregroundMask, foregroundMask, 10, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

        int totalpixels = foregroundMask.rows * foregroundMask.cols;
        int white = countNonZero(foregroundMask);
        double x = double(white) / totalpixels;

        // std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mm);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        cout << i << " " << step_i << " " << x << endl;
        // density[i][step_i] = x;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

        // }

        // fout << i << " " << x << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    video = argv[1];
    threads = stoi(argv[2]);
    VideoCapture cap(video);

    if (cap.isOpened() == false)
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the video file" << endl;
        cin.get(); //wait for any key press
        return -1;
    }

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    while (true)
    {
        Mat frame;
        bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

        //Breaking the while loop at the end of the video
        if (bSuccess == false)
        {
            cout << "Found the end of the video" << endl;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            int index = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES);

            if (index % 8 == 0)
            {
                frames.push_back(frame);
            }
        }
    }

    //uncomment if you want to print all the selected frames
    //  print(cropped_frames);

    // background subtraction and queue density calculation start

    backgroundImage = imread("back.jpg");
    resize(backgroundImage, backgroundImage, Size(328.0, double(778 / threads)), 0, 0, INTER_CUBIC);

    pthread_t thread[threads];
    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) //thread creation
    {
        int *p;
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, queuedensity, (void *)(p));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) //thread joining
    {
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    }
    //queue density finish

    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start) / pow(10, 6);
    cout << "Time taken : " << duration.count() << " seconds" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is correct when I print out using `cout`.

Comment: If you preallocate (`reserve()`)  all the global vectors you can avoid resizing and threads can safely operate on the vector elements. Also makes debugging easier since objects in the vectors aren't moving around when you push.

Comment: i pre defined the density vector of size 718* no of threads.

Comment: is reserve() different from the way i defined the density vector in my code?

Comment: I see `density` declared and its first dimension initialized, but the second dimension is initialized with `threads`, an uninitialized `int`. Did you verify that `density` is correctly sized?

Comment: @sweenish thank you, I found the mistake.

Comment: I feel like this code could be a *lot* simpler and still reproduce the problem. In fact, cutting it down could easily help you find the problem

Comment: There is no reason for using `pthread` stuff instead of  `std::thread` and `std::mutex`. The latter is also more convenient and portable.

Comment: @rustyx actually this code is part of my course assignment where i've specifically told to implement using pthreads that's why i used pthreads.

Comment: Some additional notes: You're missing `#include <fstream>` and newer OpenCV2 has renamed   `CV_BGR2GRAY` => `COLOR_BGR2GRAY` and `CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES` => `CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES` - With that fixed, I was able to compile - but got a SEGV on the first line in `main` because I didn't start with an argument. (`video = argv[1];`)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you.